# How to convert eps files to Adobe Illustrator version 10 EPS via python

Tags: python, adobe, adobe-illustrator

i am looking for python code that converts eps files to Adobe Illustrator version 10. can you help?

```
import subprocess
import os

def convert_to_ai10(input_eps, output_ai10_eps):
    # Full path to the Ghostscript executable (adjust the path as needed)
    ghostscript_path = r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe'

    # Full path to the input EPS file
    full_input_eps = os.path.abspath(input_eps)

    command = [
        ghostscript_path,
        '-sDEVICE=eps2write',  # Hedef cihaz EPS
        '-dEPSCrop',           # Crop to bounding box
        '-o', output_ai10_eps, # Hedef AI 10 uyumlu EPS dosyası adı
        full_input_eps         # Full path to the input EPS file
    ]

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()

    print("Output:", output.decode('utf-8'))
    print("Error:", error.decode('utf-8'))

input_eps_file = 'a.eps'
output_ai10_eps_file = 'output_ai10.eps'

convert_to_ai10(input_eps_file, output_ai10_eps_file)
```

wrote this code chatgpt but it never works. can you help?

Comment: The eps2write device would **create** EPs files, not turn the into Illustrator files. Don't rely on what AIs tell you. You **could** use the pdfwrite device to create a PDF file, and Illustrator **might** be able to read that.

Comment: Please, describe more closely what exactly you're trying to do. Right now it looks like the most obvious solution would be a JSX script for Illustrator. And you can run this script with Python (at least on Windows in can be done pretty easy) if you want. But it's need installed Illustrator of course. And if you mean to open EPS files of newest versions you have to install the newest version of Illustrator.